# How to create a smooth zoom and display an overlay when another HTML element gets hovered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

1st problem: I am trying to display the text overlay when the "point" class gets hovered, but for me works just the display when the "caption" class gets hovered, how to fix it?

2nd problem: I need to create a smooth zoom in image when the "point" class gets hovered, how can i do it?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/0qgcn2uu/12/

HTML:

```
<div class="caption">
    <span class="point"></span>
    <img src="http://www.blasdale.com/pictures/2007/Hendon/thumbs/IMG_3337.jpg" />
    <div class="caption__overlay">
        <div class="caption__overlay__content">
            <img id="hello" class="caption__media" src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-TH7ATkZ55uw/VOatQSMgt4I/AAAAAAAAAUM/bB199rdZMuE/s1600/alone.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.caption {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}

.caption::before {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: transparent;
    transition: background .35s ease-out;
}

.captionHover::before {
    background: rgba(248, 214, 215, .5);
}

/* I want that when i hover on the circle, the image would get this overlay, but this doesn't work */
.point:hover: + .caption::before {
    background: rgba(248, 214, 215, .5);
}

.point {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background-color: black;
}

.caption__overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
    transform: translateY(100%);
    transition: -webkit-transform .35s ease-out;
    transition: transform .35s ease-out;
}
.caption:hover .caption__overlay {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
}

.caption {
    display: inline-block;
}

.caption__media{
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".point").mouseenter(function() {
      $('.caption').addClass('captionHover'); 
   });

   $('.point').mouseleave(function() {
       $('.caption').removeClass('captionHover'); 
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is the [Adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors), [General sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) and [ftransform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box
}

figure{
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  z-index:1;
  position: relative
}
figure span{
  display: block;
  width: 16px;
  height:16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
  z-index: 2;
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer
}
figure img, figure figcaption{
  -webkit-transition: 1s ease
}

figure figcaption{
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: white
}

figure span:hover + img{
  -webkit-transform: scale(2,2)
}
figure span:hover ~ figcaption{
  top: 50%
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <span class=point></span>
  <img src="http://www.blasdale.com/pictures/2007/Hendon/thumbs/IMG_3337.jpg" />
  <figcaption>HELLO!</figcaption>
</figure>
```